# Handling dictionary generator from graph calculus with Networkx

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, networkx

Here my probleme :

Assuming this graph :

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

user_network_G = user_trust_cardinality_network.subgraph([30,40,71,145,638,783,893])

nan_edge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in user_network_G.edges(data=True) if math.isnan(d["Trust"])]
real_edge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in user_network_G.edges(data=True) if math.isnan(d["Trust"]) == False]

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(user_network_G) 

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(user_network_G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(user_network_G, pos, edgelist = real_edge, width=2)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(user_network_G, pos, edgelist = nan_edge, width=2, style="dashed")

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(user_network_G, pos, font_size=12, font_family="sans-serif")
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(user_network_G, pos, edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(user_network_G,'Trust') , font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif', label_pos = 0.6)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(user_network_G, pos, edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(user_network_G,'Intersection') , font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif', label_pos = 0.4)


plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

Giving :

[image: My_Graph]

Where :

- The integers on the edges are the cardinality of products set in common between two users (the nodes)
- The decimals on the edges are the truth score between two nodes (i.e two users)

Now i want to compute the edge value of non existing edges between two nodes (for example between node 30 and node 40).

To achieve this i firstly create my graph (the one depicted above) :

```
user_trust_cardinality_network = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(user_local_trust_computation(normalized_user_rating_matrix)[1].reset_index(level = ['User_U','User_V']), 'User_U', 'User_V', ['Trust', 'Intersection', 'Pondered_Trust'])
#Creation of the graph from a table containing for each existing paire of nodes the Trust Score, the Cardinality and the Pondered_Trust_Score

user_trust_cardinality_network.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(user_trust_cardinality_network))
#Remove selfloop edges

edges_to_predict = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in user_trust_cardinality_network.edges(data=True) if math.isnan(d["Trust"]) == True]
#Storing the set of edges to predict (edges where trust is NaN)

edges_to_predict_sub = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in user_trust_cardinality_network.subgraph([30,40,71,145,638,783,893]).edges(data=True) if math.isnan(d["Trust"]) == True]
#Edges to predict on my subgraph (for quick example computation)

user_trust_cardinality_network.remove_edges_from([(u, v) for (u, v, d) in user_trust_cardinality_network.edges(data=True) if math.isnan(d["Trust"]) == True])
#Remove edges to predict, to add them after with the newly computed score
```

Then i compute the score of the removed edges with :

```
def short_path_trust (graph, edges_to_predict,cutoff) :

    short_path_trust_dict = {}
    
    for (u,v) in edges_to_predict :
        for edges_path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(graph, u, v, cutoff):
            pondered_trust = [d['Pondered_Trust'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            intersection = [d['Intersection'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            short_path_trust_dict = {'Path%s' % [u,v] : sum(pondered_trust)/sum(intersection)}
            print(short_path_trust_dict)
```

Giving me this :

```
short_path_trust(user_trust_cardinality_network.subgraph([30,40,71,145,638,783,893]), edges_to_predict_sub, 2)

{'Path[40, 30]': 0.08499999999999999}
{'Path[40, 30]': 0.16333333333333333}
{'Path[40, 638]': 0.07833333333333332}
{'Path[40, 638]': 0.10333333333333333}
{'Path[40, 638]': 0.1572}
{'Path[145, 30]': 0.075}
{'Path[145, 30]': 0.05444444444444444}
{'Path[30, 638]': 0.017499999999999998}
{'Path[30, 638]': 0.01}
{'Path[30, 893]': 0.16555555555555557}
{'Path[30, 893]': 0.19486486486486487}
{'Path[893, 638]': 0.1581578947368421}
{'Path[893, 638]': 0.062}
{'Path[893, 638]': 0.19}
```

My problem is that the result seems to be a dictionary generator, hence a set of independent dictionnaries. It's not a dictionary of dictionary (i already invegasting this possibility), here the proof :

```
def short_path_trust (graph, edges_to_predict,cutoff) :

    short_path_trust_dict = {}
    
    for (u,v) in edges_to_predict :
        for edges_path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(graph, u, v, cutoff):
            pondered_trust = [d['Pondered_Trust'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            intersection = [d['Intersection'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            short_path_trust_dict = {'Path%s' % [u,v] : sum(pondered_trust)/sum(intersection)}
            print(type(short_path_trust_dict))
```

Return :

```
short_path_trust(user_trust_cardinality_network.subgraph([30,40,71,145,638,783,893]), edges_to_predict_sub, 2)

<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
```

Here is my main problem, if i call for creating a database :

```
def short_path_trust (graph, edges_to_predict,cutoff) :

    short_path_trust_dict = []
    
    for (u,v) in edges_to_predict :
        for edges_path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(graph, u, v, cutoff):
            pondered_trust = [d['Pondered_Trust'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            intersection = [d['Intersection'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            short_path_trust = [((u,v), sum(pondered_trust)/sum(intersection))]
            short_path_trust_df = pd.DataFrame(short_path_trust, columns= ['Nodes','Path_Trust'])
            print(short_path_trust_df)
```

I get :

```
short_path_trust(user_trust_cardinality_network.subgraph([30,40,71,145,638,783,893]), edges_to_predict_sub, 2)

     Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (40, 30)       0.085
      Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (40, 30)    0.163333
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (40, 638)    0.078333
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (40, 638)    0.103333
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (40, 638)      0.1572
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (145, 30)       0.075
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (145, 30)    0.054444
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (30, 638)      0.0175
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (30, 638)        0.01
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (30, 893)    0.165556
       Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (30, 893)    0.194865
        Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (893, 638)    0.158158
        Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (893, 638)       0.062
        Nodes  Path_Trust
0  (893, 638)        0.19
```

Yet, my goal is to get one DataFrame like this :

```
   Nodes     Path_Trust
0  (40, 30)       0.085
1  (40, 30)    0.163333
2  (40, 638)   0.078333
3  (40, 638)   0.103333
4  (40, 638)     0.1572
5  (145, 30)      0.075
6  (145, 30)   0.054444
7  (30, 638)     0.0175
8  (30, 638)       0.01
9  (30, 893)   0.165556
10 (30, 893)   0.194865
11 (893, 638)  0.158158
12 (893, 638)     0.062
13 (893, 638)      0.19
```

Or, better :

```
  Node1 Node 2     Trust
0  40    30        0.085
1  40    30     0.163333
2  40    638    0.078333
3  40    638    0.103333
4  40    638      0.1572
5  145   30        0.075
6  145   30     0.054444
7  30    638      0.0175
8  30    638        0.01
9  30    893    0.165556
10 30    893    0.194865
11 893   638    0.158158
12 893   638       0.062
13 893   638        0.19
```

I hope i well explained my problem.
If you need more informations i'll do my best to provide them.
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you create a new dictionary for each node pair, that has the same name as the old dictionary, so you are overwriting your data.
Even if you fixed that, you would run into the issue of having duplicate keys when you compare the same nodes.

Instead, I would recommend using a list, like so:

```
def short_path_trust (graph, edges_to_predict,cutoff) :

    short_path_trust_list = []
    
    for (u,v) in edges_to_predict :
        for edges_path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(graph, u, v, cutoff):
            pondered_trust = [d['Pondered_Trust'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            intersection = [d['Intersection'] for (x,y,d) in graph.edges.data() if (x,y) in edges_path or (y,x) in edges_path]
            
            short_path_trust_list.append([u,v, sum(pondered_trust)/sum(intersection)])
    return pd.DataFrame(short_path_trust_list, columns=['node1', 'node2', 'trust'])
```

As a general thing, while your post is very detailed, I cannot reproduce your problem, because you did not define the graph you took a subgraph from.

Comment: Thanks you, it works ! My general graph comes from a quite big data base containing nodes pair and edges' attributes. I wanted to link the database, but in the satckoverflow's guide on how writting a good post they advice to not link any database.
Anyway thank you again !

Comment: Glad this helped. If you cannot link to your data, you can create dummy data. In general, the easier it is for people to reproduce your problem (copy+pasting the code from your question), the more likely you are to get help :)